# Pandas evaluate a string ratio into a float

Tags: python, pandas, eval

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date        Ratios
2009-08-23  2:1
2018-08-22  2:1
2019-10-24  2:1
2020-10-28  3:2
```

I want to convert the ratios into floats, so 2:1 becomes 2/1 becomes 0.5, 3:2 becomes 0.66667.

I used the following formula

```
df['Ratios'] = 1/pd.eval(df['Ratios'].str.replace(':','/'))
```

But I keep getting this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'list'`

What's wrong with my code and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why're you doing a 1/pd.eval()...Will it not be 1/2 instead of 2/1 in this case?

Comment: Are you sure your `Ratios` column has all sane values?

Comment: that is the entire dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use `pd.eval` for `Series`, because if more like 100 rows it return ugly error, so need convert each value separately:

```
df['Ratios'] = 1/df['Ratios'].str.replace(':','/').apply(pd.eval)
```

But also your error seems some non numeric values together with `:`.

Error for 100+ rows:

> AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis'

---

If not working and still error you can try test if data are correct in custom function:

```
print (df)
         Date Ratios
0  2009-08-23   2:1r
1  2018-08-22    2:1
2  2019-10-24    2:1
3  2020-10-28    3:2


def f(x):
    try:
        pd.eval(x)
        return False
    except:
        return True


df = df[df['Ratios'].str.replace(':','/').apply(f)]
print (df)
         Date Ratios
0  2009-08-23   2:1r
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - It is bug :(

Comment: yeah it works fine on my linux, but when I switch over to my Mac, the same code doesn't work

Comment: @anarchy - There are same versions of pandas?

Comment: probably not, I didn't bother checking, but, I ran conda update on both

Comment: no but im saying your code works, just that the one I posted doesn't work anymore, thanks for your response

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution using [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) if your data is in correct format,

```
s = df['Ratios'].str.split(':')
df['Ratios'] = s.str[1].astype(float) / s.str[0].astype(float)
```

---

```
# print(df)
         Date    Ratios
0  2009-08-23  0.500000
1  2018-08-22  0.500000
2  2019-10-24  0.500000
3  2020-10-28  0.666667
```

Comment: This should be faster than `apply(pd.eval)`

Comment: @Erfan yeah, i guess so.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function which will help you in generating the decimal fractions from ratios.

> ```
> def convertFraction(x):
>     arr = x.split(":")
>     fraction = float(arr[0])/float(arr[1])
>     return fraction
>
> df["Fractions"] = df["Ratios"].apply(lambda x:convertFraction(x))
>
> print(df)
> ```